# Prove inequality $x\cdot\ln(x) + y\cdot\ln(y) \geq (x+y)\cdot \ln(x+y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, logarithms, jensen-inequality

I have inequality $$x\cdot\ln(x) + y\cdot\ln(y) \geq (x+y)\cdot \ln(x+y)$$
I transformated it to $$2^{x+y}\cdot x^x\cdot y^y\geq(x+y)^{x+y}$$ And I got stuck. Please help

Comment: As stated, the inequality does not hold. Plug $x=100$ and $y=200$ to check.

Comment: $x\ln x + y\ln y - (x+y)\ln (x+y)=x\ln \frac{x}{x+y} + y \ln\frac{y}{x+y}<0$ for $x,y>0$

Comment: It's unclear where your $2^{x+y}$ comes from. It should be equivalent to $x^xy^y>(x+y)^{x+y}$. And, as others have noted, this is false (although the reverse inequality is true.) The true inequality is a statement about information theory, but that might be more than you wanted to know. :)

Comment: Ah, the $2^{x+y}$ comes because you probably wanted $x\ln x +y\ln y >(x+y)\ln\frac{x+y}{2}$, per Michael Rosenberg's answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for it. I already asked to delete the question

Answer (score 5):

It's obviously wrong! 
Try $x=y=1$.

By the way, since $f(x)=x\ln{x}$ is a convex function, we obtain:
$$\frac{x\ln{x}+y\ln{y}}{2}\geq\frac{x+y}{2}\ln\frac{x+y}{2},$$
which gives $$x\ln{x}+y\ln{y}\geq(x+y)\ln\frac{x+y}{2}$$

Comment: Ah, that's probably the inequality OP wanted, since otherwise, it is hard to explain the $2^{x+y}$ is the work shown.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's false ...

But the map $f:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R},t\mapsto x\ln(x)$ is convex and hence :

$$\forall(x,y)\in(0,+\infty)^2,\,f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\le\frac 12\left(f(x)+f(y)\right)$$

That is :

> $$\forall(x,y)\in(0,+\infty)^2,\,x\ln(x)+y\ln(y)\ge(x+y)\ln\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Contradictory example: Let $x=e=y$, the inequality claims $$ e+e > (2e)\cdot(1+\ln(2)) $$ which is wrong.